# How to re-update query after hit back button on browser and page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, session-variables

**I was set values in session when user on first page when he click the back button session variables also set with it**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Seats']))
{
    $Eventid = $_SESSION['Eventid'];
    $stmt = $con->prepare(
        'UPDATE fistevent SET `Status`=" " where `Event_Id`=? AND `seats`=? AND `Status`="Hold" '
    );
    $stmt->bind_param(
         "st",$_SESSION['Eventid'],
          $_SESSION['Seats']
    );
    $stmt->execute();
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
}
```

**these values are came from other page through POST method**

```
if(isset($_POST['EventId']))
        {
        $Price=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['Price']);
        $TicketType=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['TicketType']);
        $EventId=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['EventId']);
        }
        $stmt = $con->prepare("select * from fistevent WHERE  row_name LIKE 'A%'");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['EventId']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $numRows = $result->num_rows;
        if($numRows > 0) {
        echo '<ul id="sub" class="sub">';
       while($r = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
**displaying vlaues here came from database**

}
        else
        {
            echo "No seats Available";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about browser caching.

The back button loads a cache version of the page.

Try to set with this code, May be it is helpful to you

```
<?php
header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    // Date in the past
header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  // HTTP/1.1
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

Comment: Its not working. i was execute the same query on second page.when user click the back button on browser it went back to first page in this time i want to execute same query on first page

Comment: try with a redirect to another page after destroying session.`header('Location:test.php');` like this.It will not generate back button.

Comment: but when we use this header('Location:test.php'); other part of page which getting the values from other page are destroyed the all values .

Comment: you should `session_start();` on every page.is it so?

Comment: yes iam using session_start();. but other values of page comes through  $_POST Method .iam using session only for above condition. okay i'll update my code then check

Comment: there is another way to sort out  this issue by using  "window.onbeforeunload" .if we use update query in it..is that possible or not?

Comment: i think you can reset form data using this function.no further idea about it.